# MySql gap in autoincrement ids

Tags: mysql

I wrote a crawler which safes a huge amount of records in mysql.

Once in a while some auto increment ids are missing and there is an gap of  1-200 ids. I'm not deleting anything from the database, thus I'm little bit surprised.

Has anyone any idea, why this happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [auto increment primary leaving gaps in counting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582704/auto-increment-primary-leaving-gaps-in-counting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will happen. It is due to MYSQL's scalability, because otherwise it would be forced to run all transactions in series, without any parallelism. 
The thing is that it will not affect you in any way.